# how to change ionic tab color from controller

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I need to change the color of the ionic tab from controller , i have changed the tittle bar color from controller like this..
 in html page i wrote ..

```
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive" ng-style="{'background-color': viewColor}">
            <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>

         </ion-nav-bar>
```

and in controller i called ..

```
 $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function() {
     $rootScope.viewColor = 'green';
  });
```

and in css i wrote ..

```
    .nav-bar-block, .bar {
              background-color: inherit !important;
            }
```

In the same way can i change the color of the tab ...
Is there any way to achieve it ??
 Any help would be appreciated...

Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry......no answer for this qsn...??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

test this code,can use `style` Instead `ng-style`

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive" style="background-color:{{viewColor}}">
    <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

&

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function() {
   $rootScope.viewColor = 'green';
});
```

---

or You can use an existing style in this url http://ionicframework.com/docs/components

for example green style for header

```
<div class="bar bar-header {{bar_style}}">
  <h1 class="title">bar-balanced</h1>
</div>
```

&

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function() {
   $rootScope.bar_style = 'bar-balanced';
});
```